# asp.net core mvc: split hosting and business-logic/ui into separate projects

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-standard

I want to separate my solution into at least two parts:

- Hosting-technology (Initializing Kestrel and setting up all the middleware, e.g. swashbuckle, authentication)
- Business-Logic & UI

because I want the hosting configuration to be replacable in later stages of the development process.

I tried simply moving all the folders containing controllers, models and views into a separate project, like shown in the image below:

Two projects with hosting configuration and business-logic separated:

[image]

So I

- moved those folders to the *.Implementation project
- added a nuget-reference to the package "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc"
- referenced the *.Implementation project from the *.Host project
- added this class to the "Controllers"-folder in the *.Implementation project:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace MyApp.Implementation.Controllers
{
    public class ExampleController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult<int> Index()
        {
            return 5;
        }
    }
}
```

If I start the application and open http://localhost:5000/example in my browser, I get the result "5" in my browser. This shows to me that the hosting technology finds my controller in the separate project.

But when I open http://localhost:5000 in the browser, I get an exception page telling me that the views for the Home-Controller where not found. The Console also shows the exception:

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found. The following locations were searched:
/Views/Home/Index.cshtml
/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
/Pages/Shared/Index.cshtml
```

Since the webhost finds my controller, I would expect that it finds the views too. It seems not so.

How can I tell the webhost where to look for the views instead? Or do I need to do anything to them instead?

Comment: Have a look at [Application Parts in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/app-parts?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: I suppose UI are very tightly-coupled with the hosting technology, enforcing separation may need a hacky solution. I understand the need of separating business logic, but should you really separating the UI engine?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to Kirk Larkin's comment to look at [Application Parts in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/app-parts), you might also want to check out [Razor Class Libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class).

I have not tried it myself yet, but it looks it might provide a solution for your issue.

Answer (score 3):

The problem when you move your controller folder, it can not detect your controllers anymore in your `Startup.cs`.

There should be a line in there saying:

```
     app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

According to [this](http://rion.io/2016/06/27/extending-mvc-controllers-from-external-assemblies-and-projects/) link, what you should do is add a namespace to it like so:

```
   app.UseMvc(routes =>
      routes.MapRoute(  
         name: "Default",
         url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
         defaults: new { controller = "Foo", action = "Index", id =      UrlParameter.Optional },
         // This will prioritize routes within your main application
         namespaces: new[] { "ProjectA.Controllers"}
      );
    });
```

Hope this will be useful for you.